# Flutter: Testing for exceptions in widget tests

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

How do I go about making sure the ui (widget) throws an exception during widget testing in Flutter. Here is my code that does not work:

```
expect(
  () => tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.send)),
  throwsA(const TypeMatcher<UnrecognizedTermException>()),
);
```

It fails with the following error

```
...
Expected: throws <Instance of 'TypeMatcher<UnrecognizedTermException>'>
  Actual: <Closure: () => Future<void>>
   Which: returned a Future that emitted <null>
```

OR......should I be testing how the UI **handles** an exception by looking for error messages, etc??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To catch exceptions thrown in a flutter test, use [WidgetTester.takeException](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/takeException.html). This returns the last exception caught by the framework.

```
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.send));
expect(tester.takeException(), isInstanceOf<UnrecognizedTermException>());
```

You also don't need a `throwsA` matcher, since it is not being thrown from the method.

Comment: actually ```expect(tester.takeException(), isInstanceOf<UnrecognizedTermException>());``` worked well! Thank you

Comment: You got me thinking: "...returns the last exception caught by the framework". I would rather have my logic catch it for better design. This is valuable nonetheless. ill accept as answer in 4 min

Comment: Notice that this does not work in all situations. In some rare situations, you may want to override `FlutterError.onError` (and restore it after).

Comment: Darn!. I just ran into the FlutterError.onError issue. will post another question

Comment: Hey, what about exceptions raised in an async context? I'm having trouble trying to catch them in my test.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle async error try wrapping your test with `runZonedGuarded`. If not then `WidgetTester.takeException` should work.