# How to expect that an exception is thrown in flutter widgets test?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing

I have this test:

```
testWidgets('Controller must only be used with one widget at a time',
    (WidgetTester tester) async {
  final CustomAnimatedWidgetController controller = CustomAnimatedWidgetController();

  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            CustomAnimatedWidget(
              child: Container(),
              controller: controller,
            ),
            CustomAnimatedWidget(// this declaration will throw an exception from initState of this widget
              child: Container(),
              controller: controller,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  expect(tester.takeException(), isInstanceOf<Exception>());
});
```

Which is guaranteed to throw an exception of type `Exception` (due to using the controller two times), but the `expect` is not catching the exception. Instead, the test fails and I see my exception thrown in the console.

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262079/9142279) and [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding/takeException.html) they say this is how it must be used. What is wrong with the test?

Answer (score 2):

[This post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262024/flutter-testing-for-exceptions-in-widget-tests/54262079#54262079) shows the action to be done by the tester (a click is simulated) that will cause an exception. We can use `expect(tester.takeException(), isInstanceOf<AnExceptionClass>());` to ensure that an exception has been thrown as expected.

In your case the Widget cannot be rendered correctly. Widget test should be done with a correctly implemented Widget first.

Comment: so where is the answer to the question?

Comment: The answer is: We should implement widget tests on User actions, not the coding of an developer.

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: ok, wait for you

Answer (score 1):

Looking more into the code of `pumpWidget`, we see that it returns `TestAsyncUtils.guard<void>(...)` so the test is running in its own "zone" and that's why the exception was swallowed by the framework (even adding try catch around `pumpWidget` above didn't catch the error)

The only way I found is override `FlutteError.onError` function:

```
FlutterError.onError = (details){
// handle error here
      };
```

now the test can pass and the error thrown during test are forwarded to this method.

Comment: thumbs up for you