# How to catch an error coming from a in flutter widget test?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's a simple testwidget that reproduces the problem in a very simple way (thanks to Remi Rousselet for the simplification of the problem).

```
`void main() {
  testWidgets('MyApp Widget Test', ((WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => MovieViewModel(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => PersonViewModel(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const MaterialApp(
        home: MovieScreen(),
      ),
    ));

    expect(find.text('Movie Screen'), findsOneWidget);
  }));
}`
```

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown:
Multiple exceptions (2) were detected during the running of the current test, and at least one was
unexpected.════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54262079/18162964 answer your question?